# How did Parallax escape the Central Power Battery on Oa before the Sinestro Corps War?

Tags: dc, comics, green-lantern

At the conclusion of the *Green Lantern: Rebirth* mini-series, the Parallax entity is imprisoned in the Central Power Battery on Oa once again. It is next seen in the *Sinestro Corps Special*, where it possesses Kyle Rayner. But, how did it get out? We clearly see that Superboy-Prime and Cyborg Superman are busted out of the sciencells on Oa in the same issue, but there's no mention of how or when Parallax escaped.

Comment: Not specific to this series, but fear fuels Parallax. So, I guess someone got feared too much near him to make him powerful enough to break the prison.

Comment: Isn't the Parallax in Sinestro Corp Special recruited from the anti-matter universe? I've not read it personally, but doesn't that mean that it's not the same Parallax that's inside the battery?

Comment: No, it's definitely the same Parallax, the anti-matter universe isn't an alternate dimension like, say, Earth 2.  I've been going through the story again, and there's mention of the central battery on Oa having been sabotaged, which is why it teleported Guy, John, and Hal to Qward early in the story, and that seems like the closest I have to an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: Krona.  The Malthusian who tried to look at the beginning of the Universe with a "time viewer", and caused both the aging of the Universe, evil to spread throughout the Universe, and the birth of the Guardians of the Universe.

It was Krona, who returned after the JLA/Marvel crossover, and began secretly collecting all the Emotional Entities in order to gain absolute power over the Universe.  (I believe this happened somewhere around GLC.v4.#035, June, 2009).

It was after Sinestro's Corps was fully started that Parallax was put into Kyle Rayner. It was Sinestro's Corps (possibly with Krona, or the Anti-Monitor) who freed Superboy Prime and Hank Henshaw the Cyborg Superman from Oa.

When Krona was ready (GL.v.4#53, June, 2010), he took the Ion Entity out of Sodam Yat, who was changing his home star from red to yellow, giving all Daxamites superpowers, and brought Ion to Ryut, Atrocius' homeworld (GL.v.4#54).  Krona started to collect all the Emotional Entities as they appeared (GL.v.4#62, Mar2011), until he took them to Oa and infected the last Guardians of the Universe with them.  Parallax was put into the Green Central Power Battery to possess the Green Lantern Corps (except those who had previously fought against Parallax) (GL.v.4#64, May, 2011).

The Emotional Entities left Oa after Hal Jordan killed Krona and the Guardians of the Universe reestablished control over the Green Lantern Corps (GL.v.4#67, Aug, 2011)  The next story arc with the Emotional Entities was Relic.

Comment: Can you confirm the comics in which these event occurred?

Comment: Added comic references as best I could.

Comment: Much improved. Worthy of an upvote and a small bounty in reward for the effort.

Comment: As far as I can tell by looking at related issues, the Krona storyline this answer is referring too is a later storyline that was published during 2010-2011. It doesn't appear to explain how Parallax was no longer imprisoned within the Central Power Battery on Oa in the issue the OP referred to, _[Green Lantern: Sinestro Corps Special #1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern:_Sinestro_Corps_Special_Vol_1_1)_, which was published in 2007.

Comment: GL.v.4.Rebirth6, May 2005, specifically had the Parallax Entity put back into the Green Central Power Battery.

Comment: GL.v.4#25, Sinestro Corps War Part 11, Jan 2008, has the following quote "So we each got a piece of Parallax inside our batteries?" "A fitting prison for the living embodiment of fear, Guy Gardner, and one far safer than Oa."
Some time after GL#25 and before GL#43, Krona took the Parallax Entity and re-formed it, putting it under his control.

Comment: @jhpace1 - _"GL.v.4.Rebirth6, May 2005, specifically had the Parallax Entity put back into the Green Central Power Battery."_ Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @jhpace1 - _"Some time after GL#25 and before GL#43, Krona took the Parallax Entity and re-formed it, putting it under his control."_ This is incorrect. Parallax was divided into four parts and imprisoned within the Power Batteries of the four human GLs in _Green Lantern Vol 4 #24_ (December 2007). It remained there until it was freed by Sinestro in _Green Lantern Vol 4 #50_ (March 2010). Krona must've captured it some time after that, but this doesn't explain why it wasn't still imprisoned within the Central Power Battery on Oa in _Green Lantern: Sinestro Corps Special #1_ (August 2007).